# Должны записываться имена всех файлов в папке, а записывается только имя первого (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Задача - записать в `/storage/emulated/0/jjj.txt` полные пути к файлам в папке `/storage/emulated/0/tmp`. Код:

```
val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/storage/emulated/0/tmp")
val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
    .forEach { item -> FileWriter("/storage/emulated/0/jjj.txt").use { it.write("$item\n") } }
```

Но записывается имя только одного из файлов, даже если их больше. Как будто бы запись происходит один раз и не повторяется. Как исправить?

Comment: мне почему-то кажется что вы пишите просто последний файл, и все, вам нужно вероятнее всего формировать строку к которой будете лепить новые элементы, посмотрите какое именно имя записано и в какой последовательности у вас там файлы, мне кажется что это будет последний файл

Comment: @Andrew да, спасибо, ошибка в этом была. Каждая строчка не добавлялась, а заменяла предыдущую, и в итоге получалась последняя. Вы правы, просто добавил через переменную и всё заработало